# Adding new Records Automatically and not by User

Tags: sql, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently making a Time-sheet Management Web Application using .NET MVC4 with LINQ where each user will have a weekly Sheet of different Tasks.

I only want to know if I can add this sheet automatically for every User on a Weekly basis without adding it manually, and if I can where can I add it.

Comment: Where are you storing `sheet`. suppose I want to create sheet manually, how can I create it in your application?

Comment: Each user has a list of sheets where each sheet has a list of Tasks.
What I want to do is to create the Sheet automatically on weekly basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate it using the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) which can run jobs that include t-sql on a schedule. For example you could set up a job to run an`insert`query every week that creates new sheets for all users.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I even don't know why the question is so downvoted.